# How do I sort a Stream in reversed order with Speedment

Tags: java, java-8, speedment

I have a database table that I want to filter and then sort in reversed (descending) order. How do I express that in a Speedment stream similar to this:

```
films.stream()
    .filter(Film.LENGTH.greaterThan(120))
    .sorted(... some expression ...)
    .skip(100)
    .limit(50)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want my SQL query to be optimized by Speedment and therefore I cannot use an anonymous lambda.

Comment: As opposed to general anonymous lambda ```Comparator::reversed``` it is significant that the built-in comparators are used or else Speedment will not be able to render a fully optimized SQL query in the background.

Comment: If you change the question after I flag it, you can't complain about the flag....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in comparator for the field you want to use and apply the [Comparator::reversed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed) operation like this:

```
films.stream()
    .filter(Film.LENGTH.greaterThan(120))
    .sorted(Film.LENGTH.comparator().reversed())  // <--- Here
    .skip(100)
    .limit(50)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```